# PHP: нужно постоянное хранилище для одного целого числа

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, wordpress

Мне нужно хранить одно целое значение на WEB-сайте. Периодически его читать и менять. Подскажите пожалуйста, какой существует правильный способ решения этой задачи(с точки зрения best practices)?

Я знаю, что для постоянного хранения данных, на сайтах используют базы данных SQL. Но заводить таблицу ради одной переменной кажется избыточным. Или так и нужно делать? Может быть есть простое хранилище для пар ключ-значение? Таких, чтобы значение было произвольного типа.

Мой сайт работает на Wordpress. В Wordpress есть хранилище пар *ключ-значение*?

Answer (score 4):

С точки зрения таблицы неважно, сколько там хранится данных, может, вообще ноль. Это абсолютно нормально, если у вас будет ровно одно значение - это все равно будет проще, чем начать использовать в проекте два хранилища вместо одного. В то же время, если вы используете Wordpress, вам проще всего будет воспользоваться [механизмом опций](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC/update_option) - он использует как раз-таки таблицу, предназначенную для такого рода вещей.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно написать так:

```
// Save
$a['my_variable'] = 5;
file_put_contents( 'my_simple_data.json', json_encode( $a ) );

// Load
$a = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'my_simple_data.json' ) );
echo $a['my_variable'];
```